# How to add defined number of blank spaces in XSLT 2.0

Tags: xslt-2.0

I have an XML to Fixed length message transformation. At the end of each record I have to add spaces for example - X(4), X(15).

Is there any options to insert the spaces apart from xsl:text.

Comment: So what is your issue exactly, writing XSLT 2 code that outputs a number of spaces (for which output method?) or using your particular tool notepad++ and its key combinations to "make" (format?) XSLT? If it is about that tool that add a tag for it. With XPath you can use e.g. `(1 to 4)!' '` to create a sequence of four spaces (in XPath 2 use `for $i in 1 to 4 return ' '`), the `string-join` it as needed. Of couse in HTML output with most elements/normal CSS settings whitespace is collapsed.

Comment: I just wanted to know if I have to add blank spaces in XSLT , then apart from </xsl:text>, do we have any other option.

Comment: @MartinHonnen - Could you please suggest.

Comment: So far I have not understood what your problem is. As I said, if the problem is related to a particular editor or tool then look into fixing that editor or tool or asking people knowing about that tool by using a tag for that tool.

Comment: @MartinHonnen - I have updated the question , just wanted to know how to add n number of spaces in xslt apart from xsl:text.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can of course, for instance define a parameter or variable e.g.

```
<xsl:param name="padding" as="xs:string" select="'    '"/>
```

and then where you need it you don't use `xsl:text` but rather `<xsl:value-of select="$padding"/>`. Or as I indicated in the comment, if you want to "compute" the padding you can use an expression `<xsl:param name="padding-length" as="xs:integer" select="4"/>` and `<xsl:param name="padding" as="xs:string" select="string-join(for $in in 1 to $padding-length return ' ', '')"/>` and then use the variable with `xsl:value-of` or of course in any concat or other place. Finally your example `X(4)` or `X(15)` looks like a function call so define a function

and literally call `mf:X(4)` where you need the value e.g. with `xsl:value-of`. As with any user-defined function in XSLT 2, you need to declare and use some namespace/prefix for your function in your stylesheet e.g. `<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns:mf="http://example.com/mf" version="2.0" exclude-result-prefixes="mf">`.